# Importing my own python module

Tags: python

[image]

Can I import the test01.py like `os`, `sys` module?

I want to import the `test01.py` like:

```
import test01.py
```

In this case now, I only can import it like this:

```
from testDemo02 import test01
```

Is it possible to reach it?

Comment: Did you try `import test01`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `test01` is in the package `testDemo02` - you can tell because there is a file `__init__.py` in the directory `testDemo02`. Given that, there are a couple possibilities:

- If the *parent directory* of `testDemo02` is in the module search path (`sys.path`), but `testDemo02` itself is not, you can import your `test01` module using either

  ```
  import testDemo02.test01
  ```

  or

  ```
  from testDemo02 import test01
  ```

  I suspect this is the case since you tried the latter one and it works. This is what I would expect because I see that `__init__.py` file there.
- If `testDemo02` itself is in the search path, you will be able to import your module with just

  ```
  import test01
  ```

  I would find it strange for a directory to be in the search path when it also contains an `__init__.py` file, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys` module's path property to append your path:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/testDemo02/test01")
>>> import test01
```